# dynamic sidebar error the path cannot redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function SidebarItem({ depthStep = 10, depth = 0, expanded, item, ...rest }) {

  fetch(`http://localhost:8989/api/menu`, requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then(menu => {

      let Testing;
      let id;
      localStorage.setItem('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));

    });



  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = React.useState(true);
  const { menuName, items, Icon, path, onClick: onClickProp } = item;

  function toggleCollapse() {
    setCollapsed(prevValue => !prevValue);
  }
```

at here it always pop the eror

```
function onClick(e) {
        if (Array.isArray(items)) {
          toggleCollapse();

        }
        if (onClickProp) {
          // onClickProp(e, item);
          <Redirect to={path} />


        }
      }
```

i am a beginner in react and i found eror Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when i use function onClick. I use to create a dynamic sidebar with its own path. but it keep geeting that eror. although i tried in many different ways like using navlink, this.history.push and redirect

Comment: first, `<Redirect />` is a component. So you can't use it like that. And I think you need to add more code.

Comment: add a component?

Comment: add your code about the component.

Comment: i tried a different way and i got eror like this "Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`."

Comment: edit your question with full code.